# Delimiters around Array

Tags: amsmath, matrices, arrays

I have a figure in which I have 2 matrices and three 1-D arrays as in the image shown below.

[image]

As seen in the image the brackets (delimiters) for the array is missing. How can I get the brackets around the three 1-D arrays?  It would also be OK if I can get a box around each 1-D array.

The code I wrote for this is as follows.

```
\[ A =  \begin{bmatrix}  
 1 & 0  \\  3 & 4 \\  6 & 0 \\  0 & 0\\  0 & 0   
 \end{bmatrix} 
 B =  \begin{bmatrix}  
 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\  
 3 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
 6 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\  
 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 \\  
 0 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\
 \end{bmatrix} 
 \begin{array}{r@{\,=\ }rrr} val & 12 & 8\\[1ex]
  col & 5 & 4 & 15\\[1ex]  
  row & 1 & 13 & 6 \end{array} \]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `aligned` and nest `bmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
A = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
\quad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 3 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
 6 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{aligned}
 \text{val} &= \begin{bmatrix} 12 & 8 \end{bmatrix} \\
 \text{col} &= \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 4 & 15 \end{bmatrix} \\
 \text{row} &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 13 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `blkarray`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{blkarray}

    \begin{document}
\[ %
A = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 B = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 3 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
 6 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \quad
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{blockarray}{rrrr}%
\\[-1.5ex]
  \begin{block}{r[rr]r}
 \text{val} =  & 12 & 8\\
\end{block}
\\[-3ex]
\begin{block}{r[rrr]}
 \text{col} =  & 5 & 4 & 15\\
\end{block}
\\[-3ex]
\begin{block}{r[rrr]}
 \text{row} =  & 1 & 13 & 6\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}%
   \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

In two-columns mode you can play with `\arraycolsep` and `\BA@colsep` to fit the table to one column width:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, lipsum}

\begin{document}
\[ %
  \setlength\arraycolsep{4pt} %
  \makeatletter%
  \setlength\BA@colsep{2pt}%
  \makeatother
  A = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
  B = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
  6 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
  0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{blockarray}{rrrr}%
    \\[-1.5ex]
    \begin{block}{@{}r[rr]r}
      \text{val} = & 12 & 8\\
    \end{block}
    \\[-3ex]
    \begin{block}{@{}r[rrr]}
      \text{col} =   & 5 & 4 & 15\\
    \end{block}
    \\[-3ex]
    \begin{block}{@{}r[rrr]}
      \text{row} =  & 1 & 13 & 6\\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}%
\]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `\medmath` command or the `medsize` environment, from `nccmath`: it produces math formulae at about 80 % of `displaystyle`.

Comment: @Stormvirux: I've updated my answer for this case. Please see my updated answer.